# Installing allegro 4 on os x 10.9.4?

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, allegro

I am trying to infall allegro 4.4.2 on os x 10.9.4. Whenever I try to run the make command in terminal to compile allegro I get these two errors.

> /Users/*********/Downloads/allegro/include/allegro/platform/aintosx.h:85:25:
>   error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSQuickDrawView', superclass of >'AllegroView' @interface AllegroView: NSQuickDrawView
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
>   /Users/*********/Downloads/allegro/include/allegro/platform/aintosx.h:176:8:
>   error: unknown type name 'CGDirectPaletteRef' AL_VAR(CGDirectPaletteRef, >osx_palette);
>
> ^

Answer (score 1):

`NSQuickDrawView` allowed you to use Carbon QuickDraw functions — i.e. those inherited from the 1984 lineage — within a Cocoa-native `NSView`.

This view was never available on 64-bit targets since Carbon was never available on 64-bit targets.

Amongst other things, 10.9.4 supports only 64-bit targets. It therefore does not supply `NSQuickDrawView`. Outdated libraries like Allegro 4.4.2 cannot be built on 10.9.4.

Comment: Is there away to get around this issue (e.g. installing it without having to build it, or building it with out that faction)?

Comment: I think Allegro uses `NSQuickDrawView` to output all its graphics — a questionable decision even when it was made but there it is — so it definitely won't build without that. It looks like Xcode can still build 32-bit applications if you change the architectures so I guess if you could find a copy of the framework then you might be able to move forwards.

Answer (score 1):

You will never compile Allegro using OS X 10.9 SDK because `CGDirectPaletteRef` was removed from 10.9's headers and `NSQuickDrawView` never got 64-bit support. Your best shot is:

1. Download a Xcode 3.1 from [Apple's Download Page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) (we only want the included OS X 10.4 SDK);
2. Open the DMG, and install the "MacOSX10.4.Universal.pkg" inside "Packages";
3. If using Xcode, make this symlink: `sudo ln -s /SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/`
4. Change your project build settings:

   - Deployment Target: OS X 10.4 (appears only after the symlink, and a restart - if Xcode was open)
   - Architectures: 32-bits only
   - Base SDKs: OS X 10.4

Now, Allegro should be compilable. If you are using CMake (and you can't use `-G Xcode`), you need this when running `cmake`:

```
-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:STRING=i386
-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:STRING=10.4
-DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:STRING=/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk
```